# Input string not in correct format when using Double for Decimals

Tags: c#, string, input, integer, format

```
using System;

namespace FirstConsoleProject
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args) 
        {

            Console.Write ("Please Put IP: ");
            double userip = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine()); //Error Here <--- Input string not in correct format
            Console.Write ("The User's IP is: " + userip);
            Console.ReadKey ();


        }
    }
}
```

Basically It used to be

```
int userip = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
```

But I knew the IP was a decimal so I tried using Double, so I put

```
double userip = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine());
```

But Now The problem is when I run the code using "Double" and entering something like 1.1.1.1, It says "Input string was not in a correct format". But when I input a whole number without decimals like 23 or 2, It works... Why?

Comment: IP addresses are not decimal format, use IPAddress.TryParse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

Because an IP address is not a `double`. It is not *even* a number. It is kind of  numerical label. Just containing a dot with some numbers doesn't make it a valid double (or any numeric value).

You can parse it with [`IPAddress.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b2h863h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`IPAddress.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144109%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you like it.

Comment: I see what you mean for actual IP addresses, But for my code.. What should I put in for it to accept Decimals itself, Not just an IP Address? Because it has an incorrect format every time i put something like 1.1.1.1...

Comment: @Ivan In your code, maybe you don't _even_ need to parse it? You are not doing anything with it at all. Just get it as a string only with `string userip = Console.ReadLine();` and then `Console.Write ("The User's IP is: " + userip);`

Comment: Oh! It worked thank you, I got confused because I thought string was only for text-like characters like letters, I didn't know it could be for numbers and decimals.. I should've made it even MORE specific next time but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are not decimal format, use IPAddress.Parse or TryParse

```
IPAddress userIp = IPAddress.Parse(Console.ReadLine);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b2h863h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to add the `IPAddress` and the `IPAddress.Parse` for IP's but I'm wondering for my code how to make the program accept decimals itself without errors? It can do whole numbers like 1 or 23 but when I put decimal numbers like 1.1.1.1 it says its not in a correct format.

Comment: If you don't know what they will input, You can check the input for its format using regular expressions and then parse it using the appropriate conversion method

Comment: But in your program you are expecting a IP address so you can use TryParse , if it returns false you need to ask them to input a valid IP again

Answer (score -1):

try regex to match IP address :

```
     string userIP = Console.ReadLine();
     Match match = Regex.Match(userIP, @"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}");
     if (match.Success)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Valid IP");
     }
     else
     { 
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid");  
     }
```